# Code Analysis does not work in VS 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, analysis

I created a console app using VS2010 like below

```
int test(int i)
{   
if ( i == 0 )
    return 0;
else
    return 1;
int j = 2;
j++;

return j;
}

void deadCode(char * pa)
{
 printf("%s", pa);
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) 
{
    test(2);
    return 0;
}
```

I checked "Enable Code Analysis for C/C++ on Build" and select Rule Set "Microsoft All Rules", when I built the project, I got

1>RunCodeAnalysis:

1>  Running Code Analysis...

1>  Code Analysis Complete -- 0 error(s), 0 warning(s)

I expected "CA1804" warning for bold part in test(), another warning should be displayed for dead code deadCode().

My question is Why Code Analysis did not catch the defects? I also tried to created my rule set that only enabled CA1804 warning, but the result is same as above (Microsoft All Rules).

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

- Unused functions are not "dead code". Imagine you are writing a library - that may well expose functions to its users that it doesn't use itself.
- As for the CA1804, I can only make assumptions: Presumably the analysis doesn't go deep enough to create a full control flow graph and notice that the code after the `if/else` block can't be reached. But even if it did a full analysis, I would expect a "dead code" warning for the part of `test()` after the `if` block, not an "unused local" warning - if the code were reachable, `j` would be used.

Comment: I would have expected it to find the unreachable code inside a method though.

Comment: for first part, yes, it is true for library. but my project generates executable, so unused function means dead code.

Comment: @Liyilin Yeah, but how should a static code analyzer notice that? It would have to inspect the project configuration for that. Moreover, it's not that important to catch this kind of 'dead code'! Dead code in functions almost always means a programmer error - you implemented logic that is never reached. Unused functions may be there for a variety of reasons: Code that has been implemented but is *not yet* used, library code, ...

Comment: I modified test() as
void test(int i)
{
 int k = 18 ;
}

Same thing happened. Variable k is easy to be identified as warning CA1804, I do not know why Code Analysis could not catch this case as CA1804.